# Integrating Spring Cloud Config Server with vault backend giving I/O error on GET request with connection refused

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-config-server

I am trying to make spring cloud config server work with vault backend. I am not trying to integrate with local copy of vault. I have enterprise vault which I am trying to connect with. While doing so I am getting

`org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://mydomain:8200/v1/secret/data/configserver": Connect to mydomain:8200 [mydomain/10.223.213.6] failed: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to mydomain:8200 [mydomain/10.223.213.6] failed: Connection refused: connect`

My application.yml is as shown below

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  profiles:
    active: vault
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          host: mydomain
          scheme: https
          skipSslValidation: true
          namespace: mynamespace
          authentication: token
          token: mytoken
          kv-version: 2
```

My POM file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project.medical</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Config-Server</name>
    <description>Config-Server Demo Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Once the project is build I am trying to hit http://localhost:8888/configserver/default

I dont understand how /8200/v1/secret/data is getting concatenated to my domain uri. I have tried to hit the service via postman and pass the "X-Config-Token" in the header but getting same exception. I also removed the vault config dependency from POM after reading the spring documentation. Any help to guide me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Add to your yaml the "port" key to override the 8200 port.

Regarding the v1/secret/data/configserver path it depends on how your Enterprise serves the secrets. That depends on its version. Seems like your Vault servers is using a version < 0.10.0... try removing kv-version: 2 from your properties file

Comment: I dont want the port defined at all as the host drives the call to our vault instance. Tried removing the kv-version but getting same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own questions but found the solution to be very straight forward. Just follow the directions stated [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#vault-backend) and you should be just fine on your journey to make spring cloud config server work with vault backend.

1. In my application.yml just added kvVersion: 1, backend: "Vault directory under which your profile resides", defaultKey: "Profile directory inside which your secrets resdies"
2. Passed the cert.jks and its password as environment variables in the java run command.

```
java -jar spring-cloud-config-service.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C://MyProjects//spring-cloud-config-service//cert.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand correctly your problem.

But if you want to access within your config server a vault server on another port than the default one (8200).

According to the spring cloud website [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#composite-environment-repositories)

You can try this config :

```
    #You can change '8200' to the one you want
    spring.cloud.config.server.vault.port=8200
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I made the change but getting the same exception with status code 500. I checked with our enterprise team and they said I dont need to define any port, when hitting the uri behind the scenes VIP routes to the vault instance

Comment: I think you have to use the bootstrap context instead of application from spring to set your token like said in spring documentation : https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/#vault.config.authentication.token